# Easiest way to add short animated images/videos to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, gif

I am working on a Kinect project that requires me to prompt the user to perform gestures. I have the gesture recognition completed, but was wanting to do something a bit more fun then having the screen just say "JUMP!".

Is there a fairly painless way to add a short video, gif or something? I would obviously have to create these animations as well, but I am more concerned with adding them to the application once I have the animations.

The animations being played would have to change throughout the program, as I will be prompting the user to perform various gestures.

I am completely open to any ideas or suggestions you guys might have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to try mediaElement. Seems to be working. If anyone stumbles across this, it can easily be changed in C# by setting the source attribute.